# Evaluate real integral using residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I have some problems with evaluating integral
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^4dx}{1+x^6}$
I don't know, which contour I need to use. Who has any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are some of the usual contours you've encountered? Have you tried to use them? What results do you get by trying various contours? Note that the best way to learn is to actually try a bunch of contours until you eventually find the right one, because then you learn why some are better than others for particular problems (making mistakes is sometimes a good thing, especially if you can learn from it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the curve $\gamma_R$ for $R > 2$ defined as the top semicircle with diameter on the real axis, centre in the origin of the complex plane and radius $R$, counter-clockwise.

Then if $f(z) = \frac{z^4}{1+z^6} $ you can write $\int_{\gamma_R}f(z)dz$ as the sum of the two integrals $\int_{-R}^{R} f(x)dx + \int_{C_R} f(z) dz $ where $C_R$ is the semicircle without the diameter (note that $C_R$ is not a closed curve).

$f(z)$ has three poles inside $\gamma_R$, regardless of $R$, which are the three sixth-roots of $-1$ with positive imaginary part.

Thus, by the residue theorem, $\int_{\gamma_R}f(z)dz$ is just $2\pi i$ times the sum of those three residues, again, independent of R.

Now all you have to do is note that $\lim_{R \to \infty} | \int_{C_R} f(z) dz| \leq \lim_{R \to \infty} l(C_R) \sup \{ |f(z)| | z \in C_R \}$
$\leq  \lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{R^5\pi}{ \inf \{ |1+z^6| | z \in C_R \} } \leq  \lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{R^5\pi}{ R^6 - 1} = 0$.

Where $l(C_R)$ denotes the length of $C_R$.

Hence:
$\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{-R}^{R} f(x) dx = \int_{\gamma_3}f(z) dz$, where as I stated you can just calculate that last integral by calculating the residues at those three poles of $f(z)$.